# fatal error out of range

Tags: ios, swift, range

Here is my code to delete a conversation row in a tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Get other user id
        let userObjectId = userIds[indexPath.row]

        // query db for that id
        let matchesQuery = PFUser.query()

        matchesQuery?.whereKey("objectId", contains: PFUser.current()?.objectId)
        matchesQuery?.whereKey("accepted", contains: userObjectId)

        matchesQuery?.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if let users = objects {
                for user in users {
                    if let theUser = user as? PFUser {
                        if let accepptedUserIds = theUser["accepted"] as? [String] {
                            for acceptedUserId in accepptedUserIds {
                                for id in self.userIds {
                                    if id == acceptedUserId {
                                        self.userIds = accepptedUserIds.filter{$0 != userObjectId}
                                        PFUser.current()?["accepted"] = self.userIds
                                        PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                                            if success {
                                                if self.images.count == 1 {
                                                    self.images.remove(at: indexPath.row)  // Line raising error
                                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                                } else {
                                                    self.images.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                print("There was an error removing the match. Please try again.")   
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Eveytime I try to delete a row in table view I get a crash fatal error , out of range, can someone please tell me how to fix my code?

Thanks in advance!

The line causing problem is:

[image]

Comment: debug the code and see what `self.images` contains and what `indexPath.row` is and why the two dont match.

Comment: Please include the full error message. It is not readable in the linked image.